# jQuery, fancybox working but only when you click this image twice 

Tags: jquery, click, fancybox, live

I have a problem ...

JS

```
$('#Contact').ready(function(){
    $('a#Contact-Map').live('click',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('a#Contact-Map').fancybox({
            'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
            'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
            'speedIn'           :   600, 
            'speedOut'          :   200, 
            'overlayShow'   :   true
        });
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="Module-Frame" id="Contact">
    <a id="Contact-Map" href="./Modules/Contact/Images/mapa_big.png">
        <img src="./Modules/Contact/Images/mapa.png" alt=""/>
    </a>
</div>
```

This HTML code is loaded by .load() jQuery function.
That's working but only when you click this image twice ...

Help pls :)

---

JS with load() func

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#Menu").children().click(function(event){
        $("#Content").hide().load('./Modules/'+ event.target.id.substr(5) +'/index.php', function() {
            $(this).fadeIn();
        });
    });



});
```

HTML

```
< html  >
< head  > ...

...
<body>
...
            <div id="Menu">
                <a id="Menu-News" href="#" title="Aktualnosci"> aktualności  |
                <a id="Menu-Aboutus" href="#" title="O nas"> o nas  | 
                <a id="Menu-Contact" href="#" title="Kontakt"> kontakt  | 
                <a id="Menu-Gallery" href="#" title="Galeria"> galeria 

            </div>
...
< div id=#content> ...
```

Comment: are you able to include the entire HTML you are using or at least your load() function?

Comment: Timothy, do you have some ideas how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After many hours I solved the problem simply by change:

`$(this).fancybox({`
to:
`$.fancybox(this,{`

```
$('#Contact').ready(function(){
    $('a#Contact-Map').live('click',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.fancybox(this,{
            'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
            'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
            'speedIn'           :   600, 
            'speedOut'          :   200, 
            'overlayShow'   :   true
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: this definitely solves the issue I was having with fancybox bound to the click event of an individual <tr> within a table, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove your onclick in your html, it's triggering before your event handler.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem. After including the stylesheet it worked with a single click. From the README.md:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```